# ReactNative - Google speech

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, speech-recognition

There are several npm for this I think but what is the right npm to have a speech recognition of Google like that please?

[image]

I don't know what npm I should install to get this. Compatible with IOS and Android too please.

Comment: did you find anything useful?

Comment: Have you found the solution.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using [react-native-voice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-voice) for text-to-speech and its compatible with both IOS and android

Comment: Ok! Thanks you, I will try it. And visually, it's look like the image I showed to you?

Comment: I don't think so